# Android: Keyboard is not showing up onfocus

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have a username and password field in my main activity and when we launch the app, the keyboard comes focused on the username field.

But when You collapse the keyboard and then try to click on the `username` field, the keyboard doesn't shows up but it works for `password` field.

Here is my code:

`activity_main.xml`

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginText"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Login ID"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordText"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/loginText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loginText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/loginText"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/passwordText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:onClick="checkLogin"
            android:text="Login" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Start the background Firebase activity
    serviceIntent = new Intent(this, SendNotificationService.class);
    this.stopService(serviceIntent);

    //Attempt to show keyboard
    //RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    //relativeLayout.clearFocus();

    // Clear userSession
    user_Session = null;

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void checkLogin(View view){
    EditText loginEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginText);
    EditText passwordEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    login(loginEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString());
}
```

Please Help me in debugging the issue.

Comment: remove enabled and textIsSelectable property from xml

Answer (score 0):

Delete `android:textIsSelectable="true"` row in loginText EditText.